# connecting API in website using ebay

Tags: php, api, ebay-api

How can I connect api with websites?

I am new to the eBay API and currently developing in PHP, I have managed to use `GetItem` to import details of an order based on the `Item ID` to my website's database. But What I want to do now is to link a users account to my website and import their listings to my database. I have put the code I used for `GetItem` (below) but now I am stuck and I don't know what to use, `GetAccount`, `GetUser` or `GetSellerList`.

Comment: Its best to read http://developer.ebay.com/ first and post specific questions about the web-api access programming issues here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all items of a user and you have access to his auth token you could use the getMyEbaySelling call that will return you all items of the user.

(explainations + examples can be found here: [Can I edit A third party ebay seller's item from his seller list by API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27478890/can-i-edit-a-third-party-ebay-sellers-item-from-his-seller-list-by-api/27480857#27480857))

if you want to retrieve items from "3rd party" users from which you only have the user/account name you will need to go with the getSellerListing call can retrieve items listed by this seller. (executeable example here: https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/c0c7c76d30bd3dcaefc96f40275bdc0a)

depending on what you want to display on your website you will need to see if those informations are already contained within the response or you will need to call the getItem call for each item to retrieve additional informations that are missing

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Arjun

eBay returns 200 items in one page for one api call

```
$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ActiveList>
<Sort>Title</Sort>
<IncludeNotes>FALSE</IncludeNotes>
<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>$pageNo</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
</ActiveList>
<HideVariations>FALSE</HideVariations>
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<Version>899</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>​
EOD;


$feed = trim($feed);
$headers = array
(
'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 899',
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ' . $dev_id,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ' . $app_id,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ' . $cert_id,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: GetMyeBaySelling',
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 3'//3 For UK
);

// Send request to eBay and load response in $response
$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll");
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $feed);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
...
...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also take a look at the difference between getsellerlist and getmyebayselling. I do not think getmyebayselling can retrieve things like the users store categories, but getsellerlist can.